# Changing the background color of a pdf with Prawn?

Tags: ruby, prawn

I can't for the life of me find any documentation on how to change the background color of a pdf to something besides white?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could have the first element on a page be a filled rectangle that takes up the entire page.  `canvas` will let you work with the bounds of the entire page.

```
canvas do
  fill_color "FFFFCC"
  fill_rectangle [bounds.left, bounds.top], bounds.right, bounds.top
end
```

The following script would create [this PDF](https://s3.amazonaws.com/luke-fritz-shared/stackoverflow/colored-pages.pdf).

```
require "prawn"

def background_color(color)
  tmp_color = fill_color
  canvas do
    fill_color color
    fill_rectangle [bounds.left, bounds.top], bounds.right, bounds.top
  end
  fill_color tmp_color
end

Prawn::Document.generate("colored-pages.pdf") do
  fill_color "FF0000"

  background_color "FFFFCC"
  text "Text on page 1"

  start_new_page
  background_color "FFCCFF"
  text "Text on page 2"

  start_new_page
  background_color "CCFFFF"
  text "Text on page 3"

  start_new_page
  background_color "CCFFCC"
  text "Text on page 4"
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Sorry about not noticing it in the manual at first. It covers quite a bit, and unless you read it cover-to-cover, it's difficult to know exactly what to look for.